# Microsoft webchat autoscroll

Tags: botframework

Autoscroll does not work in webchat.
Tried the below in Chrome and Firefox latest versions

Tried this and it does not work: [Microsoft BotFramework-WebChat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121857/microsoft-botframework-webchat)

Tried this and it does not work: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1031

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <style>
          #webchat {
                     height: 50%;
                     width: 50%;
                     }
     </style>
     </head>
        <body>
          <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
          <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
          <script> 
     const styleOptions = {
                bubbleBackground: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .1)',
                bubbleFromUserBackground: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .1)',
     botAvatarInitials: 'Me',
     userAvatarInitials: 'You',
                hideUploadButton: true,   
             };
             var token = "thetoken;         
             var d1 = window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }); 
             var botContainer = document.getElementById('webchat');
      
             // Tried activityMiddleware 
             const activityMiddleware = () => (next) => (card) => {
        return (
       (children) => {
         scrollToBottom()
         return next(card)(children)
       }
        );
      };

             // Tried Store
             const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
             {},
             ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
              if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
                document.querySelector('ul[role="list"]').lastChild.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
              }
              return next(action);
              }
              );

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat({ directLine: d1, styleOptions }, botContainer,store );
            // tried window.WebChat.renderWebChat({ directLine: d1, styleOptions }, botContainer );
            // tried window.WebChat.renderWebChat({ directLine: d1, styleOptions }, botContainer,activityMiddleware );
      
      
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with
 window.WebChat.renderWebChat({ directLine: d1, store:store}, botContainer );